# linq to jquery with jquery ver jquery-1.7.2

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, json, entity-framework-4

this is my class:

```
Public Class Employeeclass
Public Property Fname As String
Public Property Lname As String
Public Property Bdate As Date
End Class
```

this is my method:

```
 <WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function Getemployee(ByVal id As Integer) As List(Of Employeeclass)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
    Dim db As New NorthwindEntities
    Return db.Employees.Where(Function(q) q.EmployeeID = id).Select(Function(q) New Employeeclass With {.Lname = q.LastName, .Fname = q.FirstName, .Bdate = q.BirthDate}).ToList()
End Function
```

and this is my script code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnsearch").click(function () {
            $("#result").addClass("loading");
            $("#result").text("");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/Getemployee",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                data: "{'id':" + $("#txtsearch").val() + "}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#result").removeClass("loading");
                    var employee = data.d;
                    if (employee.length > 0) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < employee.length; i++) {
                            $("#result").append(employee[i].Fname + ",");
                            $("#result").append(employee[i].Lname + ",");
                            $("#result").append(employee[i].Bdate + "<br/>");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

with jquery ver "jquery-1.3.2.js" every this is OK.
but when i use ver "jquery-1.7.2.js" or "jquery-1.7.2.min.js".
iam getting this error: Message=Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'id'.
**sorry for my bad english**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I every case when I use `$.ajax()` to POST data to a webmethod, I use the `JSON.stringify()` on my object to make sure it's right.

Outside of that, you might try changing the quotes around:  `'{"id":' + $("#txtsearch").val() + '}'` to see if it is having trouble with them...

Comment: `//data: "{'id':" + $("#txtsearch").val() + "}",  
//data: { id: $("#txtsearch").val() },  
//data: {"id": $("#txtsearch").val()},  
//data: JSON.stringify({ id: $("#txtsearch").val() }),
//data: JSON.stringify(tempvar),`

Comment: I'm using `data: JSON.stringify({ dept: $("#dept").val() })`  Did you try this and include the JSON2.js library?

Comment: i download JSON2.js from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/downloads and i am use your code but still getting error.

Comment: oh my god in IE9 i am getting all of error. after 12 houre i am test my code in firefox12 and this is worked.

Comment: Have you placed a breakpoint before your ajax call to see what the valuse of txtsearch is?  I have no trouble with IE9...

Answer (score 1):

Don't wrap data in a string.  Try just:

```
data: { id: $("#txtsearch").val() }
```

Answer (score 0):

sending this

```
"{'id':" + $("#txtsearch").val() + "}"
```

would just send a json string which cant be binded to an integer
instead you should send a json object wich can be binded to the id of type integer

```
data:{"id":$("#txtsearch").val()}
```

now when you sedn the request you can debug and see that the data is being sent like this

```
id=ur_value
```

Comment: make sure an input with id "txtsearch" exists. and that you are putting a valid integer in it.

Comment: you should see what request actually you are posting to the server. by getting into the developer tools(you can do this by pressing F12)

Comment: i agree with u.for the server side i use fiddler. in win8,IE10 i getting error but in firefox or chrome every my ajax code work fine. anywhere thank you for replay. sorry for my bad english